# ParametricPlot shows wrong plots for big parameters

Tags: plotting

I am using `ParametricPlot` to plot some orbits I'm working on. So, suppose I want to plot a circular orbit. Everything works perfect and this is what I get:
[image]

Now, if I plot a longer circular orbit, i.e. an orbit that runs for a longer time, this is what I get:
[image]

However, the radial coordinate is constant, as I can see from the plot of the radius:
[image]

So it seems that `ParametricPlot` messes up the plot in the long run. It took me some time to realize this, since I'm working with more complicate orbits than these circular ones.

So is there any way I can plot the actual orbits and not these weirds things I get when the parameter is very big?

Comment: You might get better help if you include your code.

Comment: Increase `PlotPoints`.  You need to have several points per revolution.

Comment: That happens even if you plot {Cos[t],Sin[t]} for very large t.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to increasing [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints) or [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion) is to use points instead of lines:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 5000}] /. Line->Point
```

[image]

To make the points smaller you could use:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 5000}] /. Line[x_] -> {AbsolutePointSize[1], Point[x]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How do I adjust the thickness of the points?

Comment: Or you can convert back to a line using [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html): `ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 5000}] /. 
 Line[pts_] :> Line[pts[[FindCurvePath[pts][[1]]]]]`

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by [`Michael E2`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2), use the option [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) **EDIT** and/or as suggested by[`Akku14`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34287/akku14) use the option [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)

**EDIT**

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 5000}, PlotPoints -> pp, 
  MaxRecursion -> mr], {{pp, Automatic, "PlotPoints"}, 
  Prepend[Range[100, 900, 200], Automatic], 
  ControlType -> SetterBar}, {{mr, Automatic, "MaxRecursion"}, 
  Prepend[Range[2, 14, 2], Automatic], ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: You get the same good result without changing PlotPoints, but with `MaxRecursion -> 10`

Comment: @Akku14 - Thanks. Edited to include use of MaxRecursion